# Which UserControl's calling Event MouseEnter?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a list of `UserControl` and I want to know which `UserControl` is calling event `MouseEnter`. I add multiple `UserControl`s on `TableLayoutPanel`.

```cs
List<MyUserControl> form = new List<MyUserControl>();

for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 200));
    if (x == 0)
       tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    form.Add(new MyUserControl());
}

for (int x = 0; x < form.Count; x++)
{    
    form[x].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Form_MouseEnter);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(form[x], x, 0);
}
```

How do I find out which `UserControl` activated the event?

Comment: Can you show us your code for your `this.Form_MouseEnter` event handler?

Comment: [ms docs for windows-forms mouseenter event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: ```(object sender, System.EventArgs e)``` should be your event-parameters, right? sender is your UserControl

Comment: Form_MouseEnter is empty actually, I need get this from MyUserControl:
        public int Codigo
        {
            set { test = value; }
            get { return test; }
        }

Comment: _Form_MouseEnter is empty actually,_ Then is won't do anything when the mouse enters any of the UCs. Put `MyUserControl enteredUC = sender as MyUserControl;`

Comment: It's works, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that should make the biggest difference is if you give a Name to your new **MyUserControl** because the default Name is an empty string. Could you try changing your code to this and see if it helps?

```
List<MyUserControl> form = new List<MyUserControl>();

for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 200));
    if (x == 0)
        tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

    // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    // Here are the changes
    MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
    myUserControl.Name = "MyUserControl_" + x.ToString("D2"); // Name it! (Default is "")                
    myUserControl.MouseEnter += MyUserControl_MouseEnter;     // Hook the MouseEnter here
    myUserControl.Codigo = 1000 + x;                          // Example to set Codigo     
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    form.Add(myUserControl); // NOTE! This is changed from 'new MyUserControl()'.
}

for (int x = 0; x < form.Count; x++)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(form[x], x, 0);
}
```

Now the handler looks like this:

```
private void MyUserControl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyUserControl myUserControl = (MyUserControl)sender;
    Debug.WriteLine(
        "MouseEnter Detected: " + myUserControl.Name + 
        " - Value of Codigo is: " + myUserControl.Codigo);
}
```

... where (based on your comment about Codigo) ...

```
class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public int Codigo 
    { 
        set 
        { 
            test = value; 
        } 
        get 
        { 
            return test; 
        } 
    }
    int test = 0;
    // Of course there is more implementation of MyUserControl that follows...
}
```

I really hope this helps you fix the problem you're having.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's helped.. but I have another problem, I can't active the event mouse enter because label's on top. I try assign the same event, but when I call MyUserControl myUserControl = (MyUserControl)sender; results in error... I really need get the return Codigo... Would there be another way to do it?

Comment: Ok, so when I was working on answering your question, I wrote my own code to make sure it worked and I also made a public repository on GitHub. If a working example would help you, you can find it [here](https://github.com/IVSoftware/hook-user-control-mouse-enter.git)

Comment: Thank you !! I still don't have a reputation for doing this :(
I will see your example now

Comment: Please look at [this video](http://ivsoftware.com/stack-overflow/hook-user-control-mouse-enter.mp4). Is this the kind of thing you're trying to do? Do I correctly understand your goal?

Comment: I saw the video, that's exactly it, but imagine a label with dock fill on top, when you enter, the event will go through the label and not through the usercontrol

Comment: Got it! Could you please post a new question, something like "Label of UserControl is hiding MouseEnter event". That is a separate question and one thing about StackOverflow is we try and answer one-at-a-time. Then show your code for the label or describe how the label is being added to the layout. Thanks! Send me the link to the new question here please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174390/label-of-usercontrol-is-hiding-mouseenter-event

Comment: I'm on it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[see in docmation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter?view=netcore-3.1)

```
this.panel1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.panel1_MouseEnter);
```

use the `sender`

```
private void panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
    var userControl = sender as MyUserControl
}
```